# Как взять элемент внутри списков и кортежей Python

Tags: python

Есть код, все работает, но проблема в том, что на выходе я получаю:

```
FilmSearchByFiltersResponse(total=400, totalPages=20, items=[FoundFilm(kinopoisk_id=1252447, imdb_id='tt9257638', name_ru='Лорды раздевалки', name_en=None, name_original='Lords of the Lockerroom', countries=[Country(country='США')], genres=[Genre(genre='спорт'), Genre(genre='для взрослых')], rating_kinopoisk=9.4, rating_imdb=9.3, year=1999, type=<FilmType.VIDEO: 'VIDEO'>, film_length=None, poster_url='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp/1252447.jpg', poster_url_preview='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp_small/1252447.jpg'), FoundFilm(kinopoisk_id=1043658, imdb_id='tt4202274', name_ru='Шоу Грязного Фрэнка', name_en=None, name_original='The Filthy Frank Show', countries=[Country(country='США'), Country(country='Австралия'), Country(country='Япония')], genres=[Genre(genre='фэнтези'), Genre(genre='комедия'), Genre(genre='музыка'), Genre(genre='короткометражка')], rating_kinopoisk=9.3, rating_imdb=9.4, year=2011, type=<FilmType.TV_SERIES: 'TV_SERIES'>, film_length=None, poster_url='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp/1043658.jpg', poster_url_preview='https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/images/posters/kp_small/1043658.jpg')
```

Хотелось бы чтобы выводились просто названия, без другой информации: Лорды раздевалки, Шоу Грязного Фрэнка

```
from kinopoisk_unofficial.kinopoisk_api_client import KinopoiskApiClient
from kinopoisk_unofficial.model.filter_country import FilterCountry
from kinopoisk_unofficial.model.filter_order import FilterOrder
from kinopoisk_unofficial.request.films.film_search_by_filters_request import FilmSearchByFiltersRequest


api_client = KinopoiskApiClient("api token") #здесь токен должен быть

request = FilmSearchByFiltersRequest()
request.add_country(FilterCountry(1, 'США'))
response = api_client.films.send_film_search_by_filters_request(request)
print(response)
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response, который Вам возвращается, это просто объект класса [FilmSearchByFiltersResponse](https://github.com/masterWeber/kinopoisk-api-unofficial-client/blob/7d57bf07a90794aac0e05fa905e82fc9fe4bf941/kinopoisk_unofficial/response/films/film_search_by_filters_response.py). А это значит, что написав response.total можно получить просто количество фильмов. А items - это просто массив данных о фильмах.

И если я нигде не ошибся, просматривая документацию, то такой код как раз и должен вывести названия фильмов

```
for film in response.items:
    print(film.name_ru)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Воспользуюсь